# Need explanation about output of R function neuralnet()

Tags: neural-network, r

I am a beginner in R. I am a bit confused about the output of the neuralnet() function in R, from package [neuralnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf).

Here it shows steps equal to thirteen. I would like to inquire about the understanding of these steps. What is the total of all the steps that occur? The data I used as many as seven before the output as shown. Then my question is, how to display the details of each step that occurs.

[image]